# Use Gnome, but Login With KDM

Tags: gnome, 10.04, kde, display-manager

I'm trying to find a way to make the login screen a KDE session in Ubuntu 10.04 while maintaining a Gnome Session after logging in. The reason for this is to change the login screen I detest. Any help on how this could be accomplished would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Chnage the KDE login screen (KDM, KDE Display Manager), with GDM (Gnome Display Manager)? or the other way around?.

Comment: Other way around. I don't want to use the GDM login screen because of the restrictions that have been put on it since anything past 10.04 as far as installing GDM login themes, so I'm trying to find a way to set it up to use KDE because I've heard that KDE can still run the old GDM login themes.

Comment: Oh, if you use GDM, you need to use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

Comment: Also, possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/70171/44179

Comment: KDM has never been able to run GDM Themes, it runs on it's own themes.

Comment: That's the issue.I don't want to run KDM as my actual session logon. I don't like the KDM interface. I do prefer the gnome, but as far as the GDM login screen goes. Yeah; you can modify the wallpaper and such, but I'm trying to find a way to fully reconfigure it's appearance like you used to be able to do with GDM themes, so I'm hoping I might be able to find a way using KDM to login and logging into a gnome session.

Comment: Thats exactly what this will do.  It will make your Display manager (lock screen, log in screen) KDM, but the rest will still be Gnome.  If thats not what you want I don't understand.

Comment: You're confusing things here. The log-in screen, is actually called a *Display Manager*, now, KDM is KDE's Display Manager, GDM is Gnome's. Using KDM **will not** log you into KDE. If you don't like the *default* KDM theme you can change it, install `systemsettings` which is the KDE settings manager from there you can *get* new themes and *change* KDM's appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Kde in awhile, but I think you need to do something like this.

Run: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` a screen will pop up giving information about display managers.

[image]

Hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then use the arrow keys to highlight `kdm` and then press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This will change your display manager to KDE's default [KDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager).  Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

***NOTE***
You might need to install `Kdm` with `sudo apt-get install kdm`