# KDE no longer available on Kubuntu instead boots gnome

Tags: kubuntu, kde

My laptop ran out of power and died on me. Now it no longer boots into KDE and is not available in the session list. Any idea on what to do?  Kinda of a nub with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try
[Reinstall package and its installed dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275719/reinstall-package-and-its-installed-dependencies)
for the package kubuntu-desktop.

That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need for re-configure the kdm package. Just set the default desktop the one You want. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/311662/21679) askubuntu answer.